# How can I hide opencart from website analyse sites like http://builtwith.com?

Tags: opencart

I use OpenCart in my website and when I analyse my website in analyse sites like http://builtwith.com everyone can find I use opencart.
Is there a way to hide opencart from website analyse sites?

Answer (score 1):

It's unclear how they detect you're using OpenCart. However, it's very likely three possibilities:

1. You have the "powered by opencart" text in your footer still. Remove it. Also from the admin page (which ideally you should have renamed anyway).
2. It might analyse the URLs e,g, /index.php?route=common/home. You can't change all these links in a vanilla installation of OpenCart but there are several extensions available that can. Just do a search for "SEO" on the extensions page.
3. It might also detect the cookies the site uses, but OpenCart's aren't particularly distinct. Maybe enough... not a whole lot you can do about that without a search/replace throughout the entire codebase.

But really, why worry? If you're worried about people trying to exploit it, just keep up-to-date with patches. Check their git repo for the latest ones https://github.com/opencart/opencart